# Concept of Internal Forces

Tags: forces, momentum, conservation-laws

The question:
A bob is suspended from a ceiling of a car which is accelerating on a horizontal Road. The bob is at rest with respect to car making an angle $\theta$ with the vertical. The linear momentum of Bob as seen from the road is increasing with time is it a violation of Conservation of Linear Momentum? If not, where is the external force which changes the linear momentum?

My attempt: (as seen from ground)
The forces acting on the bob are the tension, the gravitational attraction mg.
The car is accelerating because its engines are pushing the ground backwards and the friction is pushing the car forward. This force of friction is responsible for increase in linear momentum of the system car +bob.

So is it correct to say that the force of friction is responsible for increase in momentum of bob even though the friction is not acting on the bob directly?
Or does it also mean that the the horizontal component of the tension on the bob is no more an internal force but an external force arising due to the fiction and my understanding of internal forces is inadequate?

Also what actually is the right definition of a internal force of a system?

Comment: You must first choose what your $system$ consists of. It could be just the bob, as your first paragraph suggests, or it could perhaps be the whole car with the pendulum inside it.